# How to return data from a MySQL query in a Flask app?

Tags: python, mysql, flask

I have the following code:

```
import flask as fk
import MySQLdb
import JSONEncoder


class SpecializedJSONEncoder(JSONEncoder):
    def default(o):
        if isinstance(o, date):
            return date.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
        else:
            super(SpecializedJSONEncoder, self).default(o)

app = fk.Flask(__name__)
app.json_encoder = SpecializedJSONEncoder
app.debug = True

@app.route("/")
def home():
   return "Hello world"

@app.route("/temp")
def temp():
    db = MySQLdb.connect("localhost", "root", "","test")
    cur = db.cursor()
    query = "SELECT DATE(DTM), POM, ROUND(MIN(TMP),1) FROM dados_meteo WHERE POM = %s AND      DATE(DTM) >= %s AND DATE(DTM) <= %s"
    param = ("Faro", "2013-12-01", "2013-12-05")
    cur.execute(query, param)
    data = cur.fetchall()

    return data.json_encoder()

 if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

The error returned is: ImportError: No module named JSONEncoder

Comment: cur.fetchall() returns a list of tuples.

Comment: I was trying to get a JSON result that I could use on a Angular client. Is it possible?

Comment: You can't change what fetchall returns, but it should be possible to parse it into an appropriate format.

Comment: @JayanthKoushik I am now using simplejson for serializing. But I am getting the following error TypeError: datetime.date(2013, 12, 1) is not JSON serializable. Could you help me?

Comment: Also interesting is [Displaying database results in Python Flask: ValueError: dictionary update sequence element #0 has length 6; 2 is required](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30614046/displaying-database-results-in-python-flask-valueerror-dictionary-update-seque), could be a duplicate of the Q/A here.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Use Flask's built-in [`jsonify`](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/api/#flask.json.jsonify) function, as it is [already extended to work with dates](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/api/#flask.json.JSONEncoder):

```
from Flask import jsonify

@app.route('/temp')
def temp():
    # Load database results
    # and then ...
    return jsonify(data=cur.fetchall())
```

The data will be returned as an object with a single key (`data`) containing an array of rows (which will either be represented as arrays or objects depending on what `fetchall` returns rows as).

If you need to serialize more types (as in your case, you are getting back `date` rather than `datetime` instances, you will need to override Flask's [`json_encoder`](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/api/#flask.Flask.json_encoder) property with a subclass of [`JSONEncoder`](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/api/#flask.json.JSONEncoder) that knows how to handle your types:

```
class SpecializedJSONEncoder(JSONEncoder):
    def default(o):
        if isinstance(o, date):
            return date.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
        else:
            super(SpecializedJSONEncoder, self).default(o)
```

And then you can set it on your `Flask` instance:

```
app.json_encoder = SpecializedJSONEncoder
```

You will now be able to handle `date`s as well as `datetime`s.

Comment: Thank you @SeanVieira but the error keeps the same :-(

Comment: May I keep this code on top?
import flask as fk
from flask import jsonify
import MySQLdb as mdb
app = fk.Flask(__name__)
app.debug = True

Comment: @Hugo - yes, of course - I only put in the part that changed :-)

Comment: Thanks once again. But the error keeps the same :-(

Comment: Do I have to create a specific datetime parser?

Comment: @Hugo - yes, you will - example added.

Comment: I have the code ready. Not working. I am sorry, but could I send it to you. It's not suposed to paste it here, right?

Comment: @Hugo - if it is still related to the encoding problem, I would edit your question and add the updated code and any errors you are getting.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/47437/discussion-between-hugo-and-sean-vieira)